# Auto fill input field after Select dropdown list [ Laravel, Vuejs ]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create something that search in Product table and i select in dropdown its will display data in order table like pic below?

how can i archieve that? Anyone give me any hint?

thanks in advances...
[image]

[image]

**In my Vuetify**

i used `vue-select` package

```
<v-col md="6" cols="12">
   <label class="font-weight-bold">Select Product</label>
   <v-select v-model="search" label="name" :options="purchases"></v-select>
</v-col>
```

**In my script file**

```
<script>
    export default {
        created() {
            this.fetchData()
        },

        data() {
            return {
                form: {},
                search: '',
                items: [],

                purchase_status: ['Received', 'Partial', 'Pending', 'Ordered'],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData() {
                this.$axios.$get(`api/product`)
                .then(res => {
                    this.items = res.data;
                    console.log(this.items)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            },

            uploadFile(event) {
                const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/product/add_adjustment';
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
                let config = {
                    header: {
                        'content-Type' : 'image/*, application/pdf'
                    }
                }

                this.$axios.$post(url,data,config)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We mainly focus on your coding error , not about service supporting . So what have you tried so far in coding :>

Comment: @DavidJapan i updated my code, pls take alook..

Answer (score 0):

When you select a product in the dropdown, you'll get product_id. Use this product_id and call API to get data for the orders table.

Comment: excuse me, but can u give me any example?